# How to write the HttpWebResponse into the object

Tags: c#, wcf

It is the first time I created a website to read the wcf service. I need to convert the respond into an object. The responseFormat from service  is  WebMessageFormat.Xml I searched the web [enter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.2). There is complex object. I already added the service in reference. 
Would someone show me some examples I can reference.

There is the response string:

```
<ShippingDatesInfo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Shipping.Objects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Dates>
    <ContainerInfo>
        <ContainerID>1</ContainerID>
        <Date_Time>2017-09-20T12:35:07.8287047-07:00</Date_Time>
    </ContainerInfo>
    <ContainerInfo>
        <ContainerID>2</ContainerID>
        <Date_Time>2017-09-28T13:35:07.8287047-07:00</Date_Time>
    </ContainerInfo>
    <ContainerInfo>
        <ContainerID>3</ContainerID>
        <Date_Time>2017-09-28T14:35:07.8287047-07:00</Date_Time>
    </ContainerInfo>
            <ContainerInfo>
    <ContainerID>4</ContainerID>
        <Date_Time>2017-09-28T15:35:07.8287047-07:00</Date_Time>
    </ContainerInfo>
</Dates>
<Details>
    <Notes>Testing Note</Notes>
    <Length>20</Length>
</Details>
</ShippingDatesInfo>
```

Comment: Did you add the service reference to your project, if you did you would already have all objects created from the designer itself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-wcf-service-in-windows-forms?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Rajmond burgaj,  I added it but I  know how to read the  respond using this code "StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());               
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();". How can I desterilized it into the list?

Comment: why would you need to use StreamReader when you can access directly the classes.`ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client();` this is just an example, then you say, client.Apimethod();